# I can't reach static class field from instance variable

Tags: c#

I'm wondering I can't reach static class field from instance variable

```
    class aa
    {
        public static string b = "bb";
    }

    Console.WriteLine(aa.b); //fine
    aa f = new aa();
    f.b //error
```

Why? Do I make something wrong?

Comment: I think other languages like Java allow this, but this is not supported in C#.

Comment: Yep. static methods and properties can only be accessed from the type not an instance of the class. As such static methods do not have acces to non-static properties or methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outside you can get a static field by `ClassName.StaticVariable`, but inside the class it is similar to other instance variables. This is because static variables are owned by class, not a specific instance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members